# CSS rule generates 404 error on some browsers

Tags: css

In my server logs, I get many errors such as this:

```
File does not exist: /my/path/-moz-linear-gradient(top,white,
```

This is apparently due to the following piece of Bootstrap CSS, where some browsers must interpret `-moz-linear-gradient` as a background image to be downloaded:

```
.btn{
/* some code... */
background-color: whiteSmoke;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(white),to(#E6E6E6));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,white,#E6E6E6);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,white,#E6E6E6);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,white,#E6E6E6);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,white,#E6E6E6);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
/* more code...*/
}
```

How can I prevent such errors from happening?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you try to evaluate on which browser this happens?

Comment: Upvoted for a very interesting question.

Comment: Do you only get log errors for -moz or for other browsers too? It seems strange to me that only -moz would be failing.

Comment: I guess the reason I get the error for -moz is that it is the last background-image line. So this is the one the browser would pick as relevant when it does not understand any gradient directive

Comment: @Eric Exactly my thoughts. Perhaps adding background-image: none; as the first line would solve the problem for incompatible browsers. I am assuming any IE below 10 is breaking. Or any browser version below linear-gradient support so to say.

Comment: Does it not log anything about the requests? Not even the user-agent string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `background:` instead of `background-image:` because with `background-image` you need to set the path of the image and you are not using an image.. but a gradient as background.

This is a **Tool** that you can use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ to make the gradient and copy the code if you want, all to make it easier and fault free.

**Update after all the comments:** 
You could use a fallback image of the gradient. Like here:

```
/* fallback image */
background-image: url(images/fallback-gradient.png);
```

And that should fix your problem to.

Comment: This is not really true. Technically the gradient is considered an <image> object. And background-image takes <image> as a parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image
I have no idea why the different behaviour tho.

Comment: "The <gradient> CSS data type denotes a CSS <image> made of a progressive transition between two or more colors. A CSS gradient is not a CSS <color> but an image with no intrinsic dimensions." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient Sounds more like a browser bug to me…

Comment: Oke, i edited my answer. That you need to set a path from the image if you use `background-image`.. and that you need to use only `background` for the gradient..

Comment: @CTravel That is still false as of the CSS specification: `As with the other <image> types defined in this specification, gradients can be used in any property that accepts images.` See: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#gradients

Comment: Ok so what im saying is just a solution, but not the reason why in his code it doesn't work. true?

Comment: I believe the actual problem here is that some browser is trying to load the actual image instead of interpreting the CSS.